# Find employees with the same job as another employee in a different branch

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find employees that are branch 10, which have the same job as employees from branch 30. I'm using nested subqueries in order to do this, I just can't wrap my head around it.

```
SELECT SNAME, JOB
FROM STAFF
WHERE JOB IN (SELECT SNAME FROM STAFF);
```

This is what I have so far however I am unsure of where to go from here.

The outcome should only show the employees from branch 10

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up the sub query to pull back just distinct job from staff where branch is 30.  Then in the main query also add Branch = 10 in the where clause

```
SELECT SNAME, JOB
FROM STAFF
WHERE JOB IN (SELECT distinct JOB FROM STAFF Where Branch = 30)
and Branch = 10;
```